# Finding maximal sublist of linearly independent vectors

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Given a list of vectors `v = {v1, ..., vn}`, which is the fastest way to find a maximal sublist of linearly independent vectors? I could add the vectors one by one to a list and check for the rank of the resulting matrix, but I would like to know if there's a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check `RowReduce`...this will reduce matrix to basis.

Comment: I tried RowReduce, but that doesn't output a sublist of the original list.

Comment: you need to implement these steps..http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164016/how-to-find-maximal-linearly-independent-subsets

Comment: did u get time to check if any of these solution is working ?

Answer (score 14):

```
MatrixRank[m =
{{1, 2, 0, -3, 1, 0},
 {1, 2, 2, -3, 1, 2},
 {1, 2, 1, -3, 1, 1},
 {3, 6, 1, -9, 4, 3}}]
```

> 3

```
m[[ Flatten[ Position[#, Except[0, _?NumericQ], 1, 1]& /@
    Last @ QRDecomposition @ Transpose @ m ] ]]
```

> {{1, 2, 0, -3, 1, 0},
>   {1, 2, 2, -3, 1, 2},
>   {3, 6, 1, -9, 4, 3}}

Comment: FWIW, `RowReduce@Transpose@m` may be used in place of `Last@QRDecomposition@Transpose@m` and is [considerably faster](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DjhaW.png).

Comment: Is this solution expected to work  for "floats"?

Answer (score 2):

Taking http://www.math4all.in/public_html/linear%20algebra/chapter3.3.html as reference I have tried to do it, I have tried to follow the steps that I suggested you,

```
   MinimalSublist[x_List] := 
 Module[{tm, ntm, ytm, mm = x}, {tm = RowReduce[mm] // Transpose, 
   ntm = MapIndexed[{#1, #2, Total[#1]} &, tm, {1}], 
   ytm = Cases[ntm, {___, ___, d_ /; d == 1}]};
  Cases[ytm, {b_, {a_}, c_} :> mm[[All, a]]] // Transpose]
```

For

```
m1 = {{1, 2, 0, -3, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 1, -3, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 0, -3, 2, 
    1}, {3, 6, 1, -9, 4, 3}};
MinimalSublist[m1]
```

> {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 2}, {3, 1, 4}}

In `M` you see 1 row and n columns together,so you can transpose it to see it as `{{1, 1, 1, 3}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 4}}` column specific data.

Their count is always equal to rank of a matrix which you can check with `MatrixRank[m1]` as `3`. To verify this result use this applet link, http://www.math4all.in/public_html/linear%20algebra/example3.7/index.html