# Submatrix with linearly independent columns

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

What I want is the submatrix where all the linearly dependent rows have been eliminated.

I tried implementing [this solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34161), but it doesn't work in the following example:

```
mm = SparseArray[{{1, 3} -> 
    0.3828286316736664`, {2, 1} -> -1.`, {2, 3} -> 
    0.9238193756199684`, {3, 2} -> -0.3828286316736664`, {4, 2} -> 
    0.9238193756199684`, {5, 3} -> -0.3828286316736664`, {6, 
     3} -> -0.9238193756199684`, {7, 4} -> 
    0.0679619061399982`, {7, 5} -> 
    0.30155693875441497`, {8, 4} -> -0.9976879167925299`, {8, 5} -> 
    0.9534481699017866`, {9, 4} -> -0.0679619061399982`, {9, 8} -> 
    0.4709417025109601`, {10, 4} -> 
    0.9976879167925299`, {10, 8} -> -0.8821643343709143`, {11, 
     5} -> -0.30155693875441497`, {_, _} -> 0}, {11, 10}]


MatrixRank[mm]
```

the matrix rank is 6. We now run the recipe in the other answer, but I get the new matrix to have rank 1:

```
MatrixRank[
 mm[[Flatten[
    Position[#, Except[0, _?NumericQ], 1, 1] & /@ 
     Last@QRDecomposition@Transpose@mm]]] ]
```

Comment: But ... do you understand the "recipe"?

Comment: not much. Flatten removes one level of depth, but I don't understand what the prefix operator is doing with all those linear operators. The prefix operator help doesn't have any examples to speak of

Comment: You may read http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/193 and then all the answers in that question

Answer (score 3):

I would approach this specific straightforward example in a straightforward way.

Eliminate your matrix using `RowReduce[mm];`

```
red=RowReduce[mm]];
red//MatrixForm
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&\\
0 & 1 &0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&\\
0 & 0 &1 &0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&\\
0 & 0 &0 &1&0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&\\
0 & 0&0&0&1&0.&0.&0.&0.&0.&\\
0 & 0&0&0&0&0&0&1 &0.&0.&\\
0 & 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\
0 & 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\
0 & 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\
0 & 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\
0 & 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Now this is sufficiently easy as it leaves us with a very simple selection. The columns in `red` with a "1" identify the column vectors in `mm` that form the independent vector set.

Select the column vectors from `mm` with:

```
vectoridx = Flatten@Position[Round@Total@RowReduce[mm], 1]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8} *)

mm[[All,vectoridx]]
```

which gives you the answer.

Now I will take a slightly more comprehensive approach to illustrate how the method you tried to use works:

```
vectorstokeep = Length@vectoridx;
```

This chops off the zero vectors from the selection below:

```
mm.Transpose[RowReduce[mm]][[All, 1 ;; vectorstokeep]]
```

The difference with what you are trying is that the `QRDecompositon` is used instead of `RowReduce` to make the selection of the positions more generic (which in your case you do not need).

If you want to understand this method, break it up in three pieces:

```
red = Last@QRDecomposition@Transpose@mm
```

provides the QR reduction (more generic);

```
pos = Position[#, Except[0., _?NumericQ], 1, 1] & /@ red
```

provides the relevant columns to select. `Except[0., _?NumericQ]` identifies non-zero numbers and `Position[#, Except[0., _?NumericQ], 1, 1]` gives the position of these non-zero numbers in the matrix. The `1,1` at the end of `Position` signifies the level specification and the fact that only the first found number is returned respectively.

```
 mm[[Flatten[pos]]]
```

selects these columns.

Please note in `Except[0, _?NumericQ]` I replaced `NumericalQ` with `NumericQ` and `0` with `0.`.

Comment: oh I see, the "prefix" operator is actually a functional composition operator. Doh!

Comment: so is it working for you now?

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward way to select linearly independent rows is to compute MatrixRank[] of 1 row, 2 rows, 3 rows and so on. After that, choose positions from the list of ranks, where rank is changed.

```
LinIndependentRows[A_List] :=
  Module[{ranks},
   ranks = MatrixRank[A[[1 ;; #]]] & /@ Range[Length@A];
   FirstPosition[ranks, #] & /@ Range[MatrixRank@A]];

A = {{0, 1, -1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, -1}, {1, 1, 1, -1, -1}, 
 {-1, -1, -1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
 {0, -1, 0, -1, -1}};
pos = LinIndependentRows[A]

{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {7}}
```

This gives the list of positions of linearly independent rows. Then just choose corresponding rows from matrix A.

```
A[[Flatten@pos, All]]

{{0, 1, -1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, -1}, {1, 1, 1, -1, -1}, 
{-1, -1, -1, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0, -1, -1}}
```