# How to Get independent Rows of a Matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a m*n Matrix. I want to omit the dependent rows and get the independent one. my matrix contains complex numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(120013)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120013/12) [(34142)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34142/12)

Comment: @Szabolcs Their solution is wrong. Assuming first column and second column the same and the MatrixRank=2 then it return the first and second columns!

Comment: Did you look at both links?

Comment: @Szabolcs oh Sorry. I have only looked at the first link of the first comment and your second column. Only it seems The second Link of the First Comment worked!
Thank you so much

Comment: Here is the answer to my question which was found by @Szabolcs
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34161/51513